# How can I override the class .popover-title in boostrap.css?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-popover

I want to change the default font color in the title. 
Adding a new css after bootstrap.css in html does not work.

Here is the example: http://jsfiddle.net/Wy22s/1309/

```
$('#signalTable').DataTable({
            drawCallback: function () {
              $('[data-toggle="popover"]').each(function (index) {
    console.log(index + ": " + $(this).text());
    $(this).popover({
        placement: 'left',
        html: true,
        content: '<button id="zoomin" type="button" class="btn dismiss">+</button>&nbsp<button type="button" class="btn">-</button>',
        title: $(this).text(),
        //container: '#' + this.id,
    }).on("mouseenter", function () {
                        var _this = this;
                        $(this).popover("show");
                        $(".popover").on("mouseleave", function () {
                            $(_this).popover('hide');
                        });
                    }).on("mouseleave", function () {
                        var _this = this;
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            if (!$(".popover:hover").length) {
                                $(_this).popover("hide");
                            }
                        }, 100);
                });

});
 $('[data-toggle="popover"]').parent().on('click', '#zoomin', function (index) {
    alert($(this).closest('tr').children('td:last').text()); 
});

}
        });
```

Can anyone help me change the font color of the title?

Comment: Bootstrap does not have special specificity for popover titles. A mere `.popover-title` selector will work, assuming your stylesheet comes *after* Bootstrap's. Please share you HTML and CSS in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Added an example, thanks

Comment: I added `.popover-title {color:#472;}` to your example's css and it worked just fine, giving me an ugly green font for the title. http://jsfiddle.net/tvrdf2op/